# Python OS malfunction

Tags: python, terminal, os.system

I am designing an interface using `pythonqt`, and when I try to call my program using `os.system`, the interface freezes.

```
 def pairClicked(self,exp1,exp2):
      os.system("""cd kat
                   ./run -v pair""") #in the terminal i used to call my python interface, it runs this commands
      os.system(exp1+" "+expr2) #but here nothing happens
```

Once i kill the program the terminal says (in case of `exp1=t1` and `exp2=t2`):

```
sh 1: t1 not found
sh 2: t2 not found
```

Any ideia/sugestions of what iam doing wrong?
Take note that this is the first time I am doing anything of this kind.

**Edit:**

I've edited and used this piece of code instead

```
 p=subprocess.Popen(['cd','kat','./run', '-pair', str(test.__len__()),expr1Text,expr2Text],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
 out= p.communicate()
 print(out)
```

But it's returning `('',None)`.
I think the problem is I am using the command like `cd kat ./run -pair *len* expr1 expr2` instead of:

```
cd kat
./run -pair *len*
expr1
expr2
```

How can I use subprocess to make new lines?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like ./run is blocking.

You'll probably need to spawn an asynchronous subprocess or perhaps use another thread, so your GUI can continue working while ./run is running.